# How to make jest recognize imports relative to project root directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, require

Is it possible to make Jest work requiring modules relative to the root project directory?

For example, here's my project structure:

[image]

If I'm on notes.test.js and want to import notes.js, I need to do the following:

```js
const notes = require('../../notes.js');
```

Is it possible to configure Jest, so the line below would work from notes.test.js?

```js
const notes = require('notes.js');
```

I'd like to have that, so I could better understand what's being imported. It's okay to figure this out on a small project like that, but I'm wondering how complicated it would be on large projects. I tried to look for an answer on my own but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

After trying a little more, it seems adding this to my package.json did the trick:

```js
  "jest": {
      "moduleFileExtensions": ["js"],
      "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "bower_components", "."]
    }
```

Comment: The answers I found weren't too clear for me, so I'm just adding this in case the same thing happens to someone else.